# How to know if a Julia package is a standard buit-in package?

Tags: julia

`Dates` is a standard Julia package that I can utilize if I import it by the `using Julia` command. I don't have to install it independently and it's embedded in Julia. So, I can call it a built-in Julia package, I guess. Now, I wonder how can I determine whether a Julia package (let's say `LinearAlgebra`) is a built-in standard package. I tried `(@v1.8) pkg> st` and I didn't see the `Dates` and `LinearAlgebra` packages in the reported list.
Can I conclude that if a package isn't in the `status` report while I can import it, then it's an embedded package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages bundled in the Julia release is called standard library. You can find all of them in the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/).

If you have imported a package, you can check if its path is in `stdlib` directory using `pathof`:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> pathof(Dates)
"/home/username/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.8.2+0.x64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Dates/src/Dates.jl"
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for something like `pathof()`. Thanks.